# How do I make text to appear in multiple columns as in newspapers on Texworks?

Tags: formatting, multicol

How do I make text to appear in multiple columns as in newspapers on Texworks instead of rows?

Comment: TeXworks is an editor to write LaTeX or TeX source code, and it has nothing to do with how LaTeX or TeX formats the code/text you write.   So it would be better to remove the reference to TeXworks from the title (and the question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using [the `multicol` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol).  The `multicols` yields balanced columns, but if that is not desired one can use
the `multicols*` environment instead (as per **Guido's** comment):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand*{\Text}{%
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Suspendisse dui felis, tincidunt quis tempus vel, adipiscing a ante. 
        Curabitur blandit vulputate ligula eu bibendum. 
        Quisque sit amet magna vitae leo dignissim faucibus lacinia id nulla. 
        Proin vulputate massa id arcu condimentum vulputate. 
        Suspendisse mauris sapien, tristique et semper nec, adipiscing ac leo. 
        Pellentesque ultricies molestie urna id semper. Morbi interdum vestibulum bibendum.%
        }

\begin{document}
\noindent
Using \textbf{multicols}:
\begin{multicols}{4}
    \Text
\end{multicols}
\noindent
Using \textbf{multicols*}:
\begin{multicols*}{4}
    \Text
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but there's a problem. After a few lines of text, it goes back to the top, starting a new column of text. I don't want it to be that way. I need the text to reach the bottom of the page and then go back to top to create a new column.

Comment: Use `multicols*` instead of `multicols`. The behaviour you describe appers on the last page where columns are balanced.

Comment: @Guido: Thanks, was just doing that... Updated example to show this.